# For which $a$ the integral is convergent?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

For which $a\in\mathbb{R}$ this integral is convergent?

$$I=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{a}+x^{-a}}$$

---

Note that for $a>0$

$$\frac{1}{x^{a}+x^{-a}} = \frac{x^a}{x^{2a}+1} \sim \frac{1}{x^{a}}$$

when $x\rightarrow \infty$.

So we know that $$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{a}+x^{-a}}$$ is convergent only if $a>1$.

Now we need to consider $$I=\int_0^{1}\frac{dx}{x^{a}+x^{-a}}$$

Obviously:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{1}{x^{a}+x^{-a}}=0$$

for $a>1$, so we can conclude that $I$ is convergent whenever $a>1$.

Comment: Amplify the integrand by $x^a$, then let $t=\dfrac1{x^{2a}+1}$ , and recognize the expression of the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new integral, then employ [Euler's reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) to arrive at the desired result.

Comment: So is my result incorrect?

Comment: But in this particular case it is easy to see that at $0$ there is removable singularity... or am I wrong?

Comment: @GregMartin I think you got that wrong? If $f$ tends to zero, there is not a problem... I think the solution by OP is just fine. For the 0 to 1 part, one could do the same rewriting as was done before (looking only at $a>1$) to conclude that $f(x)\sim x^a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write this answer just to confirm that your way of working this problem is correct.

**Edit**

I just noted that the question asks for $a\in\mathbf R$ and not $a>0$ (as I first read). Note, however, that the integral is even, so you actually only have to consider $a>0$. The final result is that the integral is convergent if and only if $|a|>1$. This should be considered in your solution.

**Comment**
As a curiosity, the integral can be calculated (as indicated by @Lucian), and equals
$$
\frac{\pi}{2a}\sec\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2a}\Bigr),\quad a>1.
$$